# SQL: remove duplicate values from a select based on 2 fields

Tags: mysql

I have this simple table (omitting primary id field):

```
value - language - externID
1       default      10
1       english      10

2       english      10

3       default      10
```

I need a SQL that select every values that got language IN ('default','english') But in the case the same value got both default and english the sql should discard the "defaul" record and return only the english one.

example: `SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE externID = 10 AND language IN ('default','english') AND "prefer english if there is a record with same value with default"`

Result of the SELECT:

```
1 - english - 10
2 - english - 10
3 - default - 10
```

Is there any way to do it?
Thanks

It's like doing a GROUP BY value But with the preference of the english language.

ps. "english" is an example I need I can choose the specific language between vary

Comment: Did you edit your post? Not sure but as i wrote my first answer the ps. was not there ?°

Comment: @dksan as you can see i never edited the post it was always there :)

Comment: yep, saw this too^^ And don't seem to get the right query done. I am off in my weekend. Perhaps i get some new ideas tomorrow or on monday

Comment: ok... too bad i cant't undo my +1 to your answer now XD. Anyway i am doing this with php atm, but it's an overkil

Comment: In your example, what should be returned if the "prefered language" is chinese?  Should value 1 give Default or English?

Comment: @dems: is prefered is chinese, that query on that table should return only the 2 records with "default"

Answer (score 2):

For this particular question `max(language)` should work because d is less than e.

EDIT (Sollution that won't break):

Add `max(case language when 'default' then 0 else 1 end)`

Edit2 (Even better):

Add `max(case language when 'english' then 1 else 0 end)` so you won't even get diplicate values if you add more languages to your `in()` section

EDIT Nr. 2:

As i promised, here i am with a fresh new mondaymorning mind and got the right query for your needs :-)

Try

```
SELECT value,
       CASE group_concat(language)
         WHEN 'default' then 'default'
         ELSE LTRIM(REPLACE(group_concat(language SEPARATOR ' '),'default',''))
       END as language,
       externID
FROM demo
WHERE externID = 10
AND   language in ('default','english')
GROUP BY value;
```

Explanation:
[GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) and [LTRIM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_ltrim)

Comment: He says the language may vary, for example, chinese would break with max.

Comment: hm it isn't working... :( `SELECT *,max(case lang when 'en' then 1 else 0 end) FROM mlink WHERE portalid=10 GROUP BY value` it always return the record with lang=default :(

Comment: wait a sec, i will build a demotable in my database

Comment: this querty it's hard is it? xD

Comment: if u need the solution it's here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118753/group-by-with-preferences-based-on-another-field