# GROUP BY with preferences based on another FIELD

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to do a group by but givinig more importance to record that got a certain value in a field?

Example:

```
value - language - externID
1       default      10
1       english      10

2       english      10

3       default      10
```

Result of the SELECT:

```
1 - english - 10
2 - english - 10
3 - default - 10
```

IE: when there is the record with same "value" prefer the record with "english"

example: SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE externID = 10 AND language IN ('default','english') GROUP BY value "PREFER lang=english"

ps. "english" is an example I need I can choose the specific language between vary

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL: remove duplicate values from a select based on 2 fields.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5118009/sql-remove-duplicate-values-from-a-select-based-on-2-fields)

Comment: Why have you posted this question a second time?

Comment: i have posted this again because i riformulated my question

Comment: It would be nice to explain that in the new question, and delete your original post.  I understand editing the original is kind of pointless as nobody looks at old questions.

Comment: @andromar: i can't delete there is an answer.. tho it may be helpful for somonone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the other question, Yes123 has added a bit extra...

If the prefered language is Chinese, and a value is asscoiated with default and english, that value should have no results returned...

I understand it to mean this...

- If the group contains the searched for language, return that language
- If the group does not contain that language, but contains default ONLY, return default
- If the group does not contain that language, but contain non-default languages, return nothing

```
DECLARE
  @preferred VARCHAR(64)
SET
  @preferred = 'English'

SELECT
  value,
  (
    SELECT
      language
    FROM
      tbl [search]
    WHERE
      externID  = 10
      AND value = tbl.value
      AND language IN ('default', @preferred)
    ORDER BY
      NULLIF(language, 'default') DESC
    LIMIT
      1
  )
FROM
  tbl
WHERE
  externID = 10
GROUP BY
  value
HAVING
  COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN language IN ('default', @preferred) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

The HAVING clause just states that every record for that value must either be 'default' or the language you're searching for.

The ORDER BY and LIMIT 1 in the sub query forces 'default' to be chosen last, always.  Meaning that if the preferred language is found, that get shown in preferrence.

Comment: I accept this because it's only query that seems to do what i want, but i am not using such huge query for this simple task. I prefer parse the result in php and remove the unwanted records. Thanks all anyway

Comment: Be careful that you don't case undue overheads by wanting to process data in a different domain.  The fact is that the data resides in one system and the application another.  Even if they are on the same server, transfering all the data then processing it in PHP may not be particularly performant.  One needs to use SQL for what it's good at, and PHP for what it's good at.  And PHP is not good at processing large volumes of data.  In short - I personally would only do this in PHP if you KNOW that the data set will ALWAYS be small.  [And I doubt the PHP code will be shorter]

Comment: @dems: php code is less than 4-5 lines of code, if you wanna see it tell me. And yes normally the valumes are pretty low so PHP speed isn't a problem

Comment: Would love to see the PHP code, always eager to learn new things!

Comment: here: http://codepad.org/dA1otynf it needs 2 array, $cache and $cleanedResult. you can get how tehy are used xD

Comment: I don't believe that your code does the came thing as the SQL I have written, as based on your explanation and comments.  Using you example in the question, but searching for 'Chinese', you stipulated (in the original version of this question) that only Value 3 should be included in the results.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a case when statement:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

Give a value to english that is lower than default, or make default absurdly high, then sort on that new name (e.g. language_value) and then the externID.

```
select language, enternalID,
case 
   when language = 'english' then 1 
   when language = 'default' then 100 
end case as langVal
from tableName
order by langVal, externalID
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'case as langVal

Comment: It should mean "end as langVal". Was it too hard to google for yourself? Thyamine might have confused it with syntax from another DB. But I strongly suggest that you try to understand the solutions that are presented to you and show some effort for yourself

Comment: sorry if i am not so familiar with sql query. Anyway now there aren't errors but the query returns both default and english  (and it even repetas the record many times) `select lang, portalid,
case 
   when lang = 'en' then 1 
   when lang = 'defat' then 100 
end as langVal
from mlink
where portalid=1243
order by langVal`

Comment: @tombom thanks for adding that in.  The MySQL doc I looked at showed the 'end case as ...' whereas TSQL would be just 'end as ...'

@yes123 If you need a 'group by' then go ahead and add that in of course.

Comment: I give +1 but this isn't working even with group by sorry i accept the other answer

Answer (score 0):

Building on Thyamine's idea, you could use a `where` clause that says the current row's language is the best language for the group:

```
select  value
,       language
,       externID
from    YourTable t1
where   case language when 'English' then 3 when 'default' then 2 else 1 end =
        (
        select  max(case language when 'English' then 3 
                        when 'default' then 2 else 1 end)
        from    YourTable t2
        where   t1.value = t2.value
                and t1.language = t2.language
                and t1.externID = t2.externID
        )
group by
        value
,       language
,       externID
```

To return no rows if neither a specific language nor a default is found, use:

```
case language when 'English' then 3 when 'default' then 2 else null end
```

Since `null = null` is untrue, this will not match the where clause.

For a generic version, which prefers any language over default, use:

```
case language when 'default' = 1 else 2 end
```

This rates default below anything "else".

Comment: There is an assumption about what should be returned if the "prefered language" is chinese.  Should it return Default or English for the record where value = 1?  (This has been asked of the OP on the question he posted an hour ago.)

Comment: @Dems: Added some variants to the answer... and this question does look like a repeat :)

Comment: WOW all that stuff for this simple task?

Comment: @yes123: Well, hopefully someone will post a more concise answer, and I can learn something :)